# Django : Render Print Random Number and 0

Tags: python, django

I am currently using Django to make a form in my office. Everything is fine, until I realize there are any random number when I access the web.

```
592
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Rekonsiliasi | Matching</title>
        <style>
            th{
                text-align: center;
            }
            ul{
                list-style-type: none;
            }
        </style>
```

Because it was rendered using templates in Django, I tried to empty the template file, but it still print '0'.

```
0
```

So, I think it's not the templates problem.

Any idea about what's happened?

This is the related python code.

```
def choose(request,fl):
# fl is a form-name to show
if request.method == 'POST':
    return saving(request,fl)
else:
    return render(request,'rekonsi_db/choose.html',{'file' : fl})
```

This is my settings.py

```
 """
Django settings for web project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
# import djcelery
from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '#####'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '####',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['#####','####']

# Database configuration

config = RawConfigParser()
config.read('#####')

DATABASE_USER = config.get('database', 'DATABASE_USER')
DATABASE_PASSWORD = config.get('database', 'DATABASE_PASSWORD')
DATABASE_HOST = config.get('database', 'DATABASE_HOST')
DATABASE_PORT = config.get('database', 'DATABASE_PORT')
DATABASE_ENGINE = config.get('database', 'DATABASE_ENGINE')
DATABASE_OPENMRS = config.get('database', 'DATABASE_OPENMRS')
DATABASE_TEST = config.get('database', 'DATABASE_TEST')
DATABASE_PERSONNEL = config.get('database', 'DATABASE_PERSONNEL')

# Celery

BROKER_URL = '#####'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    '####',
    '####',
    '####',
    '####',
    'rekonsi_db'
    # 'report',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'web.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'web.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Jakarta'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '####'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

#MEDIA
MEDIA_ROOT = '####'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = '#####'
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 0
# Logging
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '####',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'warning': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '####',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'gxp': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'warning'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #####
    url(r'^rekonsi_db/$','rekonsi_db.views.settings'),
    url(r'^rekonsi_db/thanks/(\w+)/$','rekonsi_db.views.thanks'),
    url(r'^rekonsi_db/choose/(\w+)/$','rekonsi_db.views.choose'),
    url(r'^rekonsi_db/choose/(\w+)/api_yang_belum$','rekonsi_db.views.api_yang_belum'),   
)
```

This is the template:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> Rekonsiliasi | Matching</title>
        <style>
            th{
                text-align: center;
            }
            ul{
                list-style-type: none;
            }
        </style>
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "rekonsi/simplePagination.css" %}'>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src='{% static "rekonsi/index.js" %}'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='col-md-4'></div>
            <div class='col-md-4' style='font-size : 14pt; text-align : center; margin : 4px;'> <h1>Rekonsiliasi Data</h1></div>
            <div class='col-md-4'></div>
        </div>
        <form role='form'  method='POST' class='form-group'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p hidden id='file_name'>{{file}}</p>
            <div id='choosing' class='container' style='width:100%;'>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' id='submit'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm using Django 1.6 
(UPDATE : It happened to the entire django project)

Comment: So it appears you get the number of bytes transferred (at a guess) as first output in your HTML page when viewed in the browser?

Comment: How are you running Django: through the development server? What do your settings look like? What is your urls.py?

Comment: Looked like normal, buat there is a random number on top and bottom. I can't post images, so I have put a piece of page source @DanielRoseman

Comment: @Evert yeah, through Development Server. I've put settings and urls in my post. Any idea?

Comment: Can you see if there is any corresponding between the logging of the development server and the number you're seeing at the first line? E.g., the server logs the number of bytes sent as the last number on the line.

Comment: I know this might sound a little silly but have you looked for any print statements in the code? Also look in the templates to see if anything is being outputted in the base template which could be causing this.

Comment: @DanielRoseman saving is my method to handle the data submitted by the form.

Comment: @MattWritesCode I thought it before, but I find none of the print statement related to the number, and I don't use any base

Comment: I meant, show the code. You're returning the result of that function as the response. So, what does it return?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I assume this also happens for a GET request, in which case `saving` doesn't really matter here. If it's only for a POST request, then, yes, it will make the difference. But then the OP forgot some important detail.

Comment: Can you please list what middlewares you are using, and show the contents of your templates. My thinking is your context value `fl` is being displayed in the template.

Comment: @Evert , yeah. It shows the byte transfered but in hexadecimal. Still don't know why it shows though

Comment: @DanielRoseman the saving method was saving the submitted form, and then render the page again (same as the get method), I'm sorry, but In saving() there is a piece of code that I don't think my boss agree if I put in here

Comment: @MattWritesCode i've put the template, middleware I guess you can see in settings, can't you?

Comment: Well, I don't know why you can't just show what that function is returning. Alternatively, what happens if you replace that call to `saving` with a simple `return render(...)`? Then at least you'll be able to eliminate that as the cause.

Comment: @DanielRoseman done it, it still print the number. Actually, it happened to the entire project, so I guess the problem is in settings or something like that.

Comment: When did it start to happen? After you changed something, or immediately? Does it show in other browsers as well?

Comment: Does it still occur if you turn off javascript and load the page?

Comment: @Evert actually it happened to other browser too.

Comment: @MattWritesCode still occur

Answer (score 0):

Actually, later on, I tried to run other django project I had, and had the same case.

I tried to restart my laptop, run this project again (and other too), and the printed size have disappeared.

Still don't know the cause though.

Anyway, thanks for all the participation!

Comment: You'd actually hope it reappears, because otherwise this may happen on a production server, and cause more pain than now.